# How to pass parameters to constructor of dependency from within dependent class? Create provider?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, constructor, design-principles

For example, my `DependentClass` depends on some `AbstractCsv` class.
Here is the declaration of `AbstractCsv`'s factory (http://csv.thephpleague.com/instantiation/):

```
public static AbstractCsv::createFromFileObject(SplFileObject $obj): AbstractCsv
```

And here is the declaration of `DependentClass`'s constructor:

```
class DependentClass {
    public function __construct(AbstractCsv $csv) { /* implementation... */ }
    // implementation...
}
```

As you can see, to instantiate `AbstractCsv`, I need to pass in an instance of `SplFileObject` to dependency's factory function `AbstractCsv::createFromFileObject`. To create an `SplFileObject`, I need a filename. `DependentClass` stores the filename needed (or, for example, the filename is calculated dynamically within `DependentClass` at runtime).

How can I pass an instance of `AbstractCsv` into the `DependentClass`'s constructor, if:

- the filename is defined inside the `DependentClass` itself,
- and also to create an instance of `AbstractCsv`, I first have
  to create an    `SplFileObject` and then an `AbstactCsv`? It is a
  vicious circle!

I currently see the only solution to break this circle: `DependentClass` should not depend on `AbstractCsv`, but on its factory which will provide an instance of `AbstractCsv` to `DependentClass` on-demand. This also will eliminate the need to create `SplFileObject` within the `DependentClass`:

```
class DependentClass {
    public function __construct(CsvProvider $csvProvider) { /* implementation... */ }
    // implementation...
    public function someMethod($value) {
        $filename = rand($value); // somehow calculate $filename
        $csvFile = $this->csvProvider($filename);
        $csvFile->fwrite($someData);
    }
}

class CsvProvider {
    public function get(string $filename) : AbstractCsv {
        return AbstractCsv::createFromFileObject(new SplFileObject($filename));
    }
}
```

I think, this problem is common and occurs very often, right? I'm currently new to DI, so I wonder: is this solution really the right way to solve this problem? And what's the name of such factories? I called it `provider`. Is it a correct term for this?

Comment: Where the dependent class gets the filename? Can it be passed to the constructor as well?

Comment: No, it cannot. For example, the generation of filename is a part of business logic within the dependent class. Sometimes it happens, that some information needed to create the dependency is inside the dependent class. What to do in such cases to follow the DI pattern?

Comment: Yeah, then I think your approach is fine.

Comment: How often do similar situations occur? Is it OK, or it is a code smell, and do other solutions of this problem exist? How often does it happen that some business logic class produces some data, on which some classes depend, and therefore the DI container cannot inject those dependent classes?